# Accessing dotenv (.env) variables and build mode in Vite config

Tags: vite, dotenv

Following [Vite's dotenv guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html), I have been able to set up using .env variables in my project that depend on different modes (beta mode, production, etc) using different files (eg `.env.beta`, launching with `vite ... --mode beta`).

However, I would like to make some modifications to the `vite.config.ts` depending on these modes. For example, if I build with `--mode beta` I would like to change the PWA title and icon path which is instantiated in vite config as a plugin, but these are defined in `vite.config.ts`, which as I understand does not have access to the env variables (eg `import.meta.env.VITE_BETA`).

How can I get access to the build mode or env variables in `vite.config.ts` to change?

Answer (score 13):

*To add to @MichalLevy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323569/6277151) of passing a function to `defineConfig()` for [conditional config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#conditional-config) based on `mode`:*

You can use Vite's [`loadEnv()`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables) to load the `.env` file for a specific mode:

```js
                           
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
                 
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())

  const pwaTitle = `${env.VITE_PWA_TITLE ?? ''} - ${+Date.now()}`

  return {
    plugins: [
      VitePWA({
        manifest: {
          name: pwaTitle,
          ⋮
        },
      })
    ],
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-load-env?file=src%2FApp.vue,vite.config.js)

Comment: This should be added to few places that depend on vite.config.js / vite.config.ts:

    `vite`,
    `vite-plugin-pwa`, 
    `@sveltejs/kit`, 
    `@vite-pwa/sveltekit`